# MS Access Filter and make multiple checkboxs true / false based on buttons

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-forms

I have a simple inventory database with a simple search text option that filters it down to those particular items.  I would like to "check out / in" multiple items based on what is currently filtered.

So if I looked for "float", in the split form it will only show all the info for anything that had "float" in its description.  From there I would like to have a button ("Check Out") that would check all of the results of this textbox filter true, rather than clicking down each item.  I've attached a photo of what my form looks like.[Access Example Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcffM.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some code to those buttons that execute some SQL to update the status of the record behind your checkbox. Here's a sample with a print statement to show what the query string becomes before it is executed:

```
Private Sub CheckInButton_Click()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

sqlString = "UPDATE tbl_inventory SET tbl_inventory.Packed = False WHERE tbl_inventory.Item like '" & Me.txtFilter & "'" 

debug.print sqlString

DoCmd.RunSQL sqlString 

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Me.SubForm.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, its close.  Can you let me know what I am missing here?  I am getting: 

Run-time error '3075':  Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'tbl_inventory.item like *'float'*'.  

I have never done anything with SQL commands, so I copied / pasted and modified what you gave me to:

Private Sub cmd_checkout_Click()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tbl_inventory SET tbl_inventory.Packed = False WHERE tbl_inventory.Item like *'" & Me.txtFilter & "'*"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Me.Requery

End Sub

Comment: Private Sub cmd_checkout_Click()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tbl_inventory SET tbl_inventory.Packed = False WHERE tbl_inventory.Item like *'" & Me.txtFilter & "'*"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Me.Requery

End Sub

Comment: For debugging sql queries in VBA I like to print them to the immediate window to see exactly what its getting:  sqlString = "UPDATE tbl_inventory SET tbl_inventory.Packed = False WHERE tbl_inventory.Item like '" & Me.txtFilter & "'" 
debug.print sqlString
DoCmd.RunSQL sqlString

Comment: Apologies, but when try the code out nothing is happening.  My table's name is "tbl_inventory", so that looks good.  My field name that I'm trying to change is "Packed", so all of that looks good to me, but I thought I would retype this incase I'm missing something small and important.  I actually don't have a subform, (I made this with a split form wizard at it worked so I was happy), but I just changed it to me.requery.  I tap my button after manually checking one box and leaving the other unchecked, all it seems to do is refresh (me.requery?).  Thoughts?

Comment: Try writing a regular query to do the update behavior you are after. That is usually a good place to start. Our VBA query will mimic your regular query.

Answer (score 0):

JShort set me onto the answer.  This is how I did this incase there's another newbie out there.

As suggested I created two update queries (qry_CheckIn / qry_CheckOut).
In my field "Packed" (the checkbox) I set the Update To: 0 (Remove the checkmark) / -1 (Add the checkmark).

In my field "Item" I put:

```
    Like "*" & [Forms]![frm_inventory]![txtFilter] & "*"
```

Which looks in my forms at my text filter search box (see image in question section).

Next part: (If you have a newer version of access turn on "Show All Actions")  I added the macro commands "on click" for each of my buttons in this order:

1. SetWarnings

   Warnings On - No
2. OpenQuery

   Query Name - qry_CheckIn (or Out)
3. RunMenuCommand

   Command - Refresh
4. SetWarnings

   Warning On - Yes

Thanks for the assist JShort.

Comment: Glad you got it to work @ESmith. Thank me by marking the question as answered ;)